# How to open the camera and dectect the nose in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```
let video;
let nose;
let poseNet;
let ml5;

function setup(){
  createCanvas (680,480);
  video = createCapture (VIDEO);
  video.hide();
  nose = createVector (width/2,height/2);
  poseNet = ml5.poseNet (video, modelReady);
  poseNet.org ('pose', getposes);
}
function getPoses (pose, gotPoses) {
  if (poses.length > 0 ) {
    let PoseNose = poses [0].pose.net;
    nose.x = poseNose.x;
    nose.y = poseNose.y;
  }
}
function modelRedy (){
  console.log ("Model loade, finally!")
  
  }
function draw (){
  background (250);
  image (video,0,0);
  fill (255,255,0);
  circle (nose.x,nose.y,20);
}
```

Above, I had wrote my code and I want that camera should open and it should detect my nose? But it isn't working. I am writing this code in p5.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Sorry I didn't define the src address of index.html.